# MS ACCESS Query for items not in table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am a beginner with SQL and I have a question regarding finding a subset of data that does not exist in another table.

Currently I have 2 tables

Table A has a single column of OrderID containing about 300 records
Table B also has a single column containing 1000 records

How do I write a SQL query that helps me identify the 700 records not in Table A?

Thank you

Comment: Is single column in table B also contains OrderId?

Comment: Yes table b has the column OrderId as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT TableB.* FROM TableB LEFT JOIN TableA ON TableВ.OrderID = TableA.OrderID WHERE TableA.OrderID is NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `NOT IN`.Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableB
WHERE OrderID NOT IN (SELECT OrderID FROM TableA)
```

**OR**

Use a join.

```
SELECT B.* 
FROM TableB B LEFT JOIN TableA A ON A.OrderID = B.OrderID 
WHERE A.OrderID IS NULL
```

Comment: It works, but it seems to be a slow query to execute. I need to wait a while before it is completed.

Comment: @user3539844: Then how about a join? Added to my answer. I would recommend the `IN` query.

Comment: Isn't IN query rather slower?